# Save image data to sqlite database in iphone

Tags: ios, image, sqlite, save

I want to save image data to my sqlite database but I can't do it ...

```
- (void) SaveData: (Article*) article :(NSMutableArray*) rssList
{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if (sqlite3_open([self.dataBasePath UTF8String], &articlesDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString* sqlFormat = @"INSERT INTO ARTICLES (guid, title, summary, mainLink, pubDate, author, imageLink, body, favorites, smallImage) VALUES ('%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', ?)";
        // Correct summary.
        NSString* summary = [NSString stringWithString:article.summary];
        summary           = [summary stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"''"];
        // Correct title
        NSString* title   = [NSString stringWithString:article.title];
        title             = [title stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"''"];
        // Correct Body
        NSString* body    = [NSString stringWithString:article.body];
        //body              = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"''"];
        // Create Insert SQL query.
        NSString* insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:sqlFormat, article.guid, title, summary, article.mainLink, article.pubDate, article.author, article.imageLink, body, article.favorite ? @"YES" : @"NO"];
        // Add to database.
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(articlesDB, [insertSQL UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            // Add to list.
            [rssList addObject:article];
            // Write Log.
            NSLog( @"Article added ... " );
        } 
        else
        {
            NSLog( @"Failed to add article. Error is:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(articlesDB) );
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(articlesDB);
    }
}
```

You can see that i have query and at the end i have smallimage and value (?)

```
@"INSERT INTO ARTICLES (guid, title, summary, mainLink, pubDate, author, imageLink, body, favorites, smallImage) VALUES ('%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', ?)";
```

I have a function that must update image value somewhere in my program: In this function i select the row with image link url when i try to write a data to the last column "SMALLIMAGE" but no result ... When I open my database file with editor i see in the last row only "NULL" like my data is not saved ...

```
- (void) SaveSmallImage: (NSData*) imgData :(NSString*) mainUrl
{
    if (sqlite3_open([self.dataBasePath UTF8String], &articlesDB) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        NSString* sqliteQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM ARTICLES WHERE IMAGELINK =  '%@'", mainUrl]; 
        sqlite3_stmt* statement;

        if( sqlite3_prepare_v2(articlesDB, [sqliteQuery UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK ) 
        {
            sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 9, [imgData bytes], [imgData length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_step(statement);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog( @"SaveBody: Failed from sqlite3_prepare_v2. Error is:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(articlesDB) );
        }

        // Finalize and close database.
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(articlesDB);
    }
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"SaveSmallImage: Failed from sqlite3_open. Error is: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(articlesDB) );
    }
}
```

Who can tell me what I do wrong ...

Comment: Here is table creation const char* sql_stmp = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ARTICLES (GUID TEXT UNIQUE, TITLE TEXT, SUMMARY TEXT, MAINLINK TEXT, PUBDATE TEXT, AUTHOR TEXT, IMAGELINK TEXT, BODY TEXT, FAVORITES TEXT, SMALLIMAGE BLOB)";

Comment: NSString* sqlFormat = @"INSERT INTO ARTICLES (favorites, smallImage) VALUES ('%@', ?)"; 
WHOT MUST I USE INSTED OF "?" %d or %f or whot ???

Comment: HI, Could you please tell me,where do we get the main url string?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[***Here is how you can Save image to SQLITE***](http://vitobrothersoft.com/2011/07/28/save-image-data-to-sqlite-database-in-iphone/):

```
// Create Images Table.
sql_stmp = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS IMAGES (URL TEXT UNIQUE, IMAGE BLOB)";
if( sqlite3_exec(articlesDB, sql_stmp, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK )
    NSLog( @"Fail to create \"IMAGES\" table. Error is: %@", errMsg );
```

And Here is function for save:

```
// Save Small Image Data by given main url 
- (void) SaveImagesToSql: (NSData*) imgData :(NSString*) mainUrl
{
    NSLog( @"\n*****Save image to SQLite*****\n" );

    const char* sqliteQuery = "INSERT INTO IMAGES (URL, IMAGE) VALUES (?, ?)";
    sqlite3_stmt* statement;

    if( sqlite3_prepare_v2(articlesDB, sqliteQuery, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK )
    {
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [mainUrl UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 2, [imgData bytes], [imgData length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_step(statement);
    }
    else NSLog( @"SaveBody: Failed from sqlite3_prepare_v2. Error is:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(articlesDB) );

    // Finalize and close database.
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```

And here is function to load images:

```
// Load images from data base with given image url 
- (NSData*) LoadImagesFromSql: (NSString*) imageLink
{
    NSData* data = nil;
    NSString* sqliteQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT IMAGE FROM IMAGES WHERE URL = '%@'", imageLink];    
    sqlite3_stmt* statement;

    if( sqlite3_prepare_v2(articlesDB, [sqliteQuery UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK )
    {
        if( sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW )
        {
            int length = sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 0);
            data       = [NSData dataWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 0) length:length];
        }
    }

    // Finalize and close database.
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);

    return data;

}
```

Comment: How do we get the main url?

Answer (score 3):

Or how can i update blob data ??

```
NSString* sqliteQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE ARTICLES SET SMALLIMAGE = '?' WHERE IMAGELINK = '@%'", mainUrl];
```

function is:

```
if (sqlite3_open([self.dataBasePath UTF8String], &articlesDB) == SQLITE_OK) 
        {
            NSString* sqliteQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE ARTICLES SET SMALLIMAGE = '?' WHERE IMAGELINK = '@%'", mainUrl];    
            sqlite3_stmt* statement;

            if( sqlite3_prepare_v2(articlesDB, [sqliteQuery UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK ) 
            {
                int result = sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 9, [imgData bytes], [imgData length], NULL);
                sqlite3_step(statement);
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog( @"SaveBody: Failed from sqlite3_prepare_v2. Error is:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(articlesDB) );
            }

            // Finalize and close database.
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            sqlite3_close(articlesDB);
        }
        else 
        {
            NSLog(@"SaveSmallImage: Failed from sqlite3_open. Error is: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(articlesDB) );
        }
```

this part of code return error 25

```
int result = sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 9, [imgData bytes], [imgData length], NULL);
```

Comment: @ViToBrothers I used your code above but I could't update my Blob field?

Answer (score 0):

To update the BLOB image: ( edited correcting few typos from the update answer below )

```
-(void) UpdateImagesToSql: (NSData *)imgData forUrl: (NSString *) mainUrl {

    NSLog( @"\n*****Updating image to SQLite*****\n",);

    const char* sqliteQuery =  NSString* sqliteQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE ARTICLES SET SMALLIMAGE = ? WHERE IMAGELINK = '@%'", mainUrl]; 

    sqlite3_stmt* statement;

    if( sqlite3_prepare_v2(articlesDB, sqliteQuery, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK )
    {
        sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 1, [imgData bytes], (int)[imgData length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_step(statement);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog( @"SaveBody: Failed from sqlite3_prepare_v2. Error is:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(articlesDB) );
    }

    // Finalize and close database.

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```

Comment: Hi,Could you please tell me where do we get the main url?

Comment: or the uri of the photo album ?