# Retrieving NSData from DB, get unrecognized selector error sent to __NSCFString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, uiimage, nsdate

I am having trouble in converting `NSData` to a `UIImage`.

I capture an image from the device camera, and convert this image into `NSData` to store it in SQLite using the BLOB data type.

The image data is successfully stored in the DB, but when I retrieve my image data, the application crashes.

I use this code:

```
NSData *tempData = [[NSData alloc] init];
tempData = [[arr_img objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Image"];

UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:tempData];
```

and get this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5f8c000'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how do you store NSData in sqlite ?

Comment: Why do you `alloc/init` to write over `tempData` immediately?

Comment: There must be something wrong in your data!!!

Comment: @Hector:i Store my data using this line
               app.picdata = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way

```
NSData *data = yourData;
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

or

```
NSData *data = yourData;
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
[image release];
```

if it does work means there may be some prob in the value of ur NSData

Answer (score 1):

Insert image into SQLite:

```
sqlite3_bind_blob(compiledStatement,i, [image_data bytes], [image_data length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

and Get image from SQLite:

```
NSData *dataForCachedImage = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(compiledStatement, i) length: sqlite3_column_bytes(compiledStatement, i)];           
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:dataForCachedImage];
```

Here 'i' is your database column number

Comment: Ok but "compiledStatement" meaning dbpath ya anything else!!

Comment: sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

Comment: @keyurbhalodiya plz refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039343/save-image-data-to-sqlite-database-in-iphone