# Can anyone help me how to save an image in sqlite3 database?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, sqlite

I'm new to iOS Developer,Can anyone help me how to save an image in sqlite3 database when i'm picking from camera and photolibrary?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15263793/397915

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you picked the image from [UIImagePickerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html), convert it into the `NSData`

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);
```

To save into the `sqlite`

```
 if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        NSString *query = @"insert into imageTable (ID, image) values (?, ?)";
        const char* quer_st = [query UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, quer_st, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            //sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, ID);
            sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 2, [imgData bytes], [imageData length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

            sqlite3_step(statement);
        } else{
            NSLog( @"SaveBody: Failed from sqlite3_prepare_v2. Error is:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database) );
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
```