# Imageview image save in SQL database using URL in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, sql

I want to save displayed UIImageview image in SQL database. I am capturing the image using the camera/albums/library which are displayed in UIImageview. I want to save this image in my SQL database using URL.

Also I need to display this image in another view.

How can I take a path(URL) of my imageview image? How can I store this path(URL) & also store & display into another view?

Comment: this might be helpful http://tricksni.blogspot.in/2012/11/good-example-to-store-images-in-sqlite.html

Comment: i read this but i don't insert the url there.my question is how can i get image view url & how can i used them?

Comment: Take a look this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/5308188/1328096

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to grab the UIImage and write to internal directory:

```
UIImageView *imageView = "[your image]";

// define your own path and storage for image
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
documentPath = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.jpg"];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 1.0);
[imageData writeToFile:documentPath atomically:YES];
```

How to get the NSURL/NSString for a file path in internal directory:

```
// specify fileURL as it is an internal file, don't use URLWithString:
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentDirectory];

// store as a string in database
NSString *fileURLString = fileURL.path;
```

Please take note that the NSURL for local file is different with normal NSURL.

```
// for normal URL
NSURL *webURL = [NSURL URLWithString:"http://www.google.com/"];
[webURL absoluteString]; // -> http://www.google.com/

// for local file path URL
NSURL *localURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:"/User/path/samplefile.ext"];
[localURL absoluteString]; // -> file://User/path/samplefile.ext
[localURL path]; // -> /User/path/samplefile.ext
```

Comment: i am already display image in imageview.but i only need this display imageview path to store into sql & used for another view.i am confused in sql part.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using SQLite for this task, please check the tutorial here for query, insert or update: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_4_iPhone_Application. You only can store string type (for URL) in database and then when you're retrieving it try to convert it back to NSURL again.

Answer (score 0):

just save name of your image in database and store image in phone memory...it will be easy  or this way try this line

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:(the file path)];
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
```