# How TO store images in sqllite3 database

Tags: ios, iphone, image, sqlite, xcode5

I have number of images and i want to store it in `sqllite3` database in `xcode`. But when I convert it into blob format it is showing a large string to store in database. Please tell me how can I solve this issue and also suggest me the code for that particular method. The Code i used is

```
image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]; 
[image_border setImage:image]; 
imgdata1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f); 
NSLog(@"%@",imgdata1);
```

Anyway to compress it.

Comment: use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039343/save-image-data-to-sqlite-database-in-iphone

Comment: are you getting any kind of error?

Comment: A blob is not a string. There is something wrong in your code.

Comment: image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        [image_border setImage:image];
        imgdata1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f);
        NSLog(@"%@",imgdata1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
sqlite3_stmt *statement = NULL;
int resultCode = 0;

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2([[ICSSSqliteManager sharedInstance] database], [mySQL cStringUsingEncoding: [NSString defaultCStringEncoding]] , -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){

    sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 1, [data bytes], [data length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    resultCode = sqlite3_step(statement);
    if (resultCode ==SQLITE_DONE) {
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);

  }
 return resultCode;
}

Here data is image data
```