# ios image display from sqlite database

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, sqlite, loadimage

I have saved my image and text into the **sqlite3** database by clicking **saveInfo** **button**.

```
- (IBAction)saveInfo:(id)sender {

    // Prepare the query string.
    NSString *query;

    if (self.recordIDToEdit == -1) {

        query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into empInfo values('%@', '%@','%@','%@','%@','%@' )", self.txtEmpCode.text, self.txtName.text, self.txtDesignation.text,self.txtDepartment.text,self.txtTagline.text,self.saveImage.image];
    }

    else{

        query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update empInfo set name='%@',empInfoCode='%@',designation='%@',department='%@',tagLine='%@',photo='%@' where empInfoCode=%d", self.txtEmpCode.text,self.txtName.text, self.txtDesignation.text,self.txtTagline.text,self.txtDepartment.text,self.saveImage.image, self.recordIDToEdit];

    }


    // Execute the query.--------------

        [self.dbManager executeQuery:query];

    //   If the query is sucessfull the show this in the dubugger.
    if (self.dbManager.affectedRows != 0) {

        NSLog(@"Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = %d", self.dbManager.affectedRows);

        // Here we inform the delegate that editing in app is finished.

        [self.delegate editingInfoWasFinished];

        // Pop the view controller.
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"%d",self.dbManager.affectedRows);
        NSLog(@"---Could not execute the query.----");
    }

}
```

Then I load the data in this method, I'm able to access the text data but can't load the image in this method.

```
-(void)loadInfoToEdit{

    // Create the query.

    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from empInfo where empInfoCode=%d", self.recordIDToEdit];

    // Load the relevant data.

    NSArray *results = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:query]];

    // Setting the loaded data to the textfields and imageView.
.
    self.txtEmpCode.text = [[results objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:[self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"empInfoCode"]];

    self.txtName.text = [[results objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:[self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"name"]];

    self.txtDesignation.text = [[results objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:[self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"designation"]];

     self.txtTagline.text = [[results objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:[self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"tagLine"]];

    self.txtDepartment.text = [[results objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:[self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"department"]];

self.saveImage.image = [[results objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:[self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"photo"]];

  //  NSLog(@"This photo has:%@",[[results objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:[self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"photo"]]);

  //  self.saveImage.image= [[results objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:[self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"photo"]];

//    NSLog(@"This Nsdata object has %@",img);
//    self.saveImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:img];

}
```

How can I load my image into **saveImage(UIImageView property)**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should save your image in your document directory. For that you should first convert image to data and then you should save(or write) that data to `documentdirectory`. and you should save name of image to your `sqlite database`

Now, when you fetch data from your database, you will got imagename, by that `imagename` you can fetch your saved image data from `document directory` and you can convert that data to image and can use as per requirement.

Example :

save image,

```
   NSString *docsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];

 NSString *profilePicturePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"profilePicture"];

 NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, 1.0);

 [data writeToFile:profilePicturePath atomically:NO];
```

You can retrieve image like,

```
 UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:profilePicturePath]];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Lion.

Comment: I can't update the image when I try to insert next image ??It shows the same image which was inserted for the last person..

Comment: Give unique name to image everytime. Ideally you should use timestamp for naming. And name in your database and in path of image must be same.

Answer (score 0):

You can't save image simply like saving string data. You will have to convert image into NSData and then save it using

```
sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 2, [imgData bytes], [imgData length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

For more info please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039343/save-image-data-to-sqlite-database-in-iphone);

Comment: Thanks @vishal sonawane